# Zend Framework Application form not rendered?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm ramping up a Zend Framework web application. I spent a long time to install apache2+MySQL5+PHP5.3+ZendFramework, and it worked once.
Then I tried to debug it in Eclipse+PDT. For this purpose I installed Zend Web Debugger and configured it, according to wiki [here](http://www.thierryb.net/pdtwiki/index.php?title=Using_PDT_%3a_Installation_%3a_Installing_the_Zend_Debugger). Then I found that it doesn't work.
The view script is as simple as:

```
<div id="login-content">
<div id="welcome">
    <h1>Tool</h1>
</div>
Please login:
<?php
$this->form->setAction($this->url());
echo $this->form;
?>
```

And I saw only text display:

Tool
    Please login:
formLabel($this->element->getName(), $this->element->getLabel()) ?>
{$this->element->helper}($this->element->getName(), $this->element->getValue(), $this->element->getAttribs()) ?>
formLabel($this->element->getName(), $this->element->getLabel()) ?>
{$this->element->helper}($this->element->getName(), $this->element->getValue(), $this->element->getAttribs()) ?>
{$this->element->helper}($this->element->getName(), $this->element->getLabel(), $attributes) ?>

It seems the form codes are displayed but not rendered.
The phpinfo() function works, and I tried the first validation method [here](http://www.webhostinghub.com/support/website/general-server-setup/test-zend-framework-installation) and all tests passed.

I even tried to disable the debugging installation but no luck. Any hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: have you added the form in the relevant controller action? such as $this->view->form = new Form_LoginForm();

Comment: Please add the code from the controller

Comment: I didn't modify the codes when this happened. It's a robust product so I don't think it has anything to do with the codes. Let me see if I can add the controller codes though.

Comment: what version of zend framework?

Comment: I reinstalled LAMP and it now works. I think the issue comes because I have multiple apache and php version on my OS X.